# i read old question but cant fix: docker Error: Unable to access jarfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-image

### hi, I am new to docker and trying to containerize a simple spring boot application. The docker file is as below.

version:
win 11
docker desktop : newest version
dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
RUN mkdir app
WORKDIR /app
# Copy the jar to the production image from the builder stage.
COPY target/taco-cloud-*.jar app/taco-cloud.jar

# Run the web service on container startup.
EXPOSE 9090
CMD ["java", "-jar", "taco-cloud.jar"]
```

docker-compose

```
version: '2.4'
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: test-data
    image: mysql:latest
    networks:
      -  kell-network
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=taco_cloud
      - MYSQL_USER=kell
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=dskell0502
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
  web:
    container_name: test-web
    image: test:ver1
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - kell-network
volumes:
    mysql-data:
networks:
  kell-network:
    driver: bridge
```

when I am trying to run docker-compose, I am getting "Error: Unable to access jarfile taco-clound.jar"
test-web   | Error: Unable to access jarfile taco-cloud.jar

---

I tried to edit the dockerfile but it still doesn't work

```
FROM maven:latest
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["mvn", "spring-boot:run"]
```

and

```
# Use the official maven/Java 8 image to create a build artifact: https://hub.docker.com/_/maven
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8-alpine as builder

# Copy local code to the container image.
RUN mkdir app
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src ./src

# Build a release artifact.
RUN mvn package -DskipTests

# Use the Official OpenJDK image for a lean production stage of our multi-stage build.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk
# https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

# Copy the jar to the production image from the builder stage.
COPY --from=builder target/taco-cloud-*.jar app/taco-cloud.jar

# Run the web service on container startup.
EXPOSE 9090
CMD ["java", "-jar", "taco-cloud.jar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY target/taco-cloud-*.jar app/taco-cloud.jar
```

1. AFAIK `COPY` command don't support `*` wildcards. You have to know exact filename or rename it to `taco-cloud.jar` before building image and run `COPY taco-cloud.jar ./taco-cloud.jar`
2. Even if `taco-cloud-*.jar` will be copied, it will be copied into `/app/app/taco-cloud.jar`. Do you mean `COPY {original_file} /app/taco-cloud.jar` or `COPY {original_file} ./taco-cloud.jar`?

Comment: i mean COPY {original_file} ./taco-cloud.jar.

Comment: I used target/taco-cloud - *. jar before and it worked. But idk why is it not working now

Comment: Hmm Error: Can't access jar file gone. Looks like it can't connect to MYSQL

Comment: `i mean COPY {original_file} ./taco-cloud.jar. ` → okay (actually it was a rhetorical question), then you have to use it without `app/`. `I used target/taco-cloud - *. jar before and it worked` → It will work for usual bash copy command `cp file*.ext file.ext` but I didn't see even one example with `*` and docker's `COPY` operation. However I didn't check it by myself so... maybe it will work, but I still not usre

Comment: Ok tks for your in4. Best regards